# ¿Se puede implementar una App para iOS sin publicarla en el AppStore?

Tags: xamarin

estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil con Xamarin pero estoy en duda aun si debo agregar un proyecto para iOS, el objetivo es para un grupo muy reducido de personas que usarán mi aplicación, se puede distribuir esta aplicación sin necesidad de publicarla en el App Store de Apple?

Será de gran ayuda sus aportes.

Saludos!

Comment: El "Enterprise program" es el que se muestra por default en la página pero el más común es el  Apple Developer Program de 99 dlls!, lo agregué en mi respuesta.

Comment: Eso es correcto, pero solamente el **Enterprise Program** permite hacer **In-house App Distribution**, que es lo que nuestro compañero necesita hacer. @Elenasys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se puede, pero necesitas estar en el **Enterprise Program** que es una membresía que se paga anualmente de US$299.

En ésta página podes ver el detalle de los planes que tiene Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Vaya! Bastante caro el pago, creo que los compañeros que tengan iOS se tendrán que conformar con la versión de mi aplicación para Windows 10 nada más.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar **TestFlight** en modo beta cerrada, lo que te permitirá distribuirlo solo a un grupo pequeño de personas usando el ID de Apple. Los usuarios necesitan instalar la app TestFlight desde la App Store la que funciona como una suerte de segunda App Store (valga la redundancia), permitiendo recibir notificaciones cuando se le invite a usar la app o tenga alguna actualización.

Te dejo el enlace: [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

Answer (score 1):

Yo recomiendo el deployment vía https://www.hockeyapp.net/
es gratis si tienes menos de 2 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un programa básico llamado **Apple Developer Program** de 99 dlls:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/how-it-works/

También existe el **Enterprise Program** que es más caro 299 USD al año, que incluye features como MediaFeed y Monitor.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/